# Update Method: how to retain the IDnum of User if the IDnum is not changed

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

my problem is if I update all data from a single user except for the `idnum`, it always shows that id number already exist? what will i do to retain the idnumber?

My code is :

```
    public bool ExistsKey(string keyField, string table, string value, SqlConnection con)
    {      
        try 
        {
            if(con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
            string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}={2}) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                     table, keyField, value), con))
            {
                var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
                return result != null && (int)result == 1;
            }
        } 
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally 
        {
            con.Close();
        }      
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (ExistsKey("idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
            FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
            FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
        }
        else if (ExistsKey("idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (sc.State != ConnectionState.Open) sc.Open();
            try
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE TableVotersInfo SET Education=@ed, idnum=@idnum, FirstName=@firstname, MiddleName=@middlename, LastName=@lastname, SchoolYear=@schoolyear, ControlNum=@controlnum WHERE id=@id
                                        SELECT @ed, @idnum, @firstname, @middlename, @lastname, @schoolyear, @controlnum
                                        WHERE @id NOT IN (SELECT idNum FROM TableVotersInfo);", sc))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", _ed);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idnum", _idnum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", _firstname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", _middlename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", _lastname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schoolyear", _schoolyear);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlnum", _controlnum);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// <-- this is what you want
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Updated!");
                    FAddVoters._cleardata = cleardata;
                    FAddVoters._checkID = "0";
                }
            } 
            catch (SqlException ex) 
            {
                if(ex.Number == 2627)//duplicated primary key 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
                   FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
                   FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
                } else 
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("There was some error while attempting to update!\nTry again later.");
                }
            }
            finally 
            {
                sc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

if I edit all the column in an specific row except the ID number, it still tells "ID number already exist!" which it shouldnt be.

Comment: What's the value of `_idnum`? Are you sure whenever you update a row, the `_idnum` does not already exist? I'm sure thhat this `Update` should be used only when you update the `_idnum`.

Comment: the code is working fine, except for one thing. Example : I want to edit a specific row in a datagrid, then when I finish editing all the fields except the `idnum` e.g "22755", then pressed the update button, The result is "ID number already exist!";

Comment: I want it to have an exception that if the `idnum` is **NOT** edited in a specific `id` then it will allow to be updated, but if the `idnum` is edited and has a same `idnum` in database, then it wont allow to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should design your table with `double primary key` composed of `id` and `idnum`. If you don't want so, try this:

```
public bool ExistsKey(string rowID, string keyField, string table, string value, SqlConnection con)
{      
    try 
    {
        if(con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
        using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}' AND id <> '{3}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
                 table, keyField, value, rowID), con))
        {
            var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
            return result != null && (int)result == 1;
        }
    } 
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally 
    {
        con.Close();
    }      
}
//Then use it like this:

if (ExistsKey(_id.ToString(), "idnum", "TableVotersInfo", _idnum.ToString(), sc)) {
    MessageBox.Show("ID number already exist!");
    FAddVoters._cleardata = "0";
    FAddVoters._checkID = checkID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `ExistsKey` method is always return false because there's an exception occured.

Try this:

```
string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}='{2}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", 
               table, keyField, value), con))
```

Comment: if I edit all the column in an specific row except the ID number, it still tells "ID number already exist!" which it shouldnt be.